# Tensorflow ValueError: No variables to optimize

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorlayer

I am trying to use 3D unet on meical image. The interface I am using is [tensorlayer](https://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). While I am trying to calculate the mean_squared_error of two tensors:

```
mse_loss = tl.cost.mean_squared_error(dense_unet3D.outputs, t_target_image, is_mean=True)
```

Here the tl stands for tensorlayer and I am using 3D dense_unet. The size of dense_unet3D.outputs is: (4, 128, 128, 128, 1) meaning (batch, depth, hight, width, channel), same as t_target_image. 
I know that in tensorlayer, the mean_squared_error could not calculate 5D tensor, so I added these code in the function **[cost](https://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/cost.html)** in tensorlayer:

```
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(output, target), [1, 2, 3, 4]), name=name)
```

And I defined the optimizer as this:

```
g_optim_init = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr_v).minimize(mse_loss, var_list=g_vars)
```

However, when the code above is executed, the error:

**ValueError: No variables to optimize.**

came out. I don't know why. Could anyone uses tensorlayer tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How is your variable list `g_vars` looks like? That could be empty which left the optimizer with no variables to optimize.

Comment: I am sorry... I found the problem. This is because my tf.name_scope is wrong in sess.run. So while sess.run() doing the optimization, It could not find the parameters under the name scope.